# how to identify multiple keywords in raw_input? python

Tags: python, raw-input

```
    if "sneak" or "assasinate" or "stealth" not in action:
        print"...cmon, you're a ninja! you can't just attack!"
        print "STEALTH, SNEAK ATTACKS, ASSASINATIONS!"
        print "The gods decide that you have come too close to loose now."
        print "they give you another chance"
        return 'woods'
    else:
        print "You throw a ninja star at a near by tree to distract the warlord,"
        print "you take out his legs, get him on the ground and have your blade to his neck"
        print "You take off his mask to stare into his eyes as he dies, and realise, it's your father."
        return 'the_choice'
```

this the bit of code i'm having a problem with. i'm new to python, and i need to know how i can identify more than one word given in raw_input. i can't figure out why that ^ doesn't work, but this does :

```
action = raw_input("> ")

if "body" in action:
    print "You hit him right in the heart like a pro!"
    print "in his last dying breath, he calls for help..."
    return 'death'
```

any help will be appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) :

```
any(x not in action for x in  ("sneak","assasinate","stealth"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues involved here:

1. Non-empty strings are inherently truthy
2. The associativity of `or` is a bit different that what you have written.

The easiest way to see this is to use only the first branch:

```
if "sneak":
   print "This was Truthy!"
```

If we added parentheses to your if clause, it would resolve like this (since it reads from left to right:

```
if ("sneak" or "assasinate") or ("stealth" not in action)
```

@AshwiniChaudhary's suggestion to use `any` is a good one, but to be clear, it would have an equivalent result to doing:

```
"sneak" in action or "assasinate" in action or "stealth" in action
```

By the by, if you were looking for an exact match, you could also do

```
if action in ("sneak", "assasinate", "stealth")
```

Comment: That last one is really all you need here.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, but i figured it out, here's what i did:

```
    action = raw_input("> ")

    if "sneak" in action:
        print "You throw a ninja star at a near by tree to distract the warlord,"
        print "you take out his legs, get him on the ground and have your blade to his neck"
        print "You take off his mask to stare into his eyes as he dies, and realise, it's your father."
        return 'the_choice'
    elif "assasinate" in action:
        print "You throw a ninja star at a near by tree to distract the warlord,"
        print "you take out his legs, get him on the ground and have your blade to his neck"
        print "You take off his mask to stare into his eyes as he dies, and realise, it's your father."
        return 'the_choice'
    elif "stealth" in action:
        print "You throw a ninja star at a near by tree to distract the warlord,"
        print "you take out his legs, get him on the ground and have your blade to his neck"
        print "You take off his mask to stare into his eyes as he dies, and realise, it's your father."
        return 'the_choice'
    else:
        print"...cmon, you're a ninja! you can't just attack!"
        print "STEALTH, SNEAK ATTACKS, ASSASINATIONS!"
        print "The gods decide that you have come too close to loose now."
        print "they give you another chance"
        return 'woods'
```

Comment: That replicates a lot of code, unless you want to use different messages for each action. And answering your own question and accepting it as the solution is dubious, especially when there were other existing solutions.

Comment: @BoppreH You're right, my code is not very DRY here. For anyone viewing this question, don't use my code, use the accepted answer.